# Inserindo datetime em SQLSRV usando PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou trabalhando com PHP e SQLSRV.

Preciso inserir um data em um campo do tipo `Datetime` e não consigo de jeito nenhum. Pelo menos não das formas que tenho encontrado em buscas na Internet.

A última que tentei foi essa, pois comentaram que funcionava:

```
if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){ 

    $dataInicio = $_POST['data'];

    $dataHoje = date("Y-m-d");

    $dataInicio['data'] = $_POST['data'];
    $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataInicio['data']);
    $data = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $dataHoje['data'] = $_POST['data']; 
    $dataHj = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataHoje['data']);
    $dataHj = $dataHj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[CAD_FUN] (DATA, DATAINI) VALUES (?,?)";

    $params = array($data, $data);
```

Porém, ao clicar em cadastrar, aparece o seguinte aviso:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: Ficaria mais fácil olhando o código que trata o comando de INSERT. Mas basicamente é melhor você usar parâmetros no seu comando SQL e passar a data como DateTime mesmo em vez de formatá-la como string. Caso prefira string, o formato universal do MS SQL Server para entrada de dados é `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Ah, quanto ao seu erro, parece que `$data` não pode receber uma instãncia de `DateTime`. Neste caso, `$_POST['data']` pode estar vazio ou conter dado inválido. Você consegue depurar?

Comment: Caffé! Segue o meu código:               if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){

     $dataInicio  = $_POST['data'];
     $dataHoje = date("Y-m-d");


  $dataInicio['data'] = $_POST['data'];
  $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataInicio['data']); 
  $data = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $dataHoje['data'] = $_POST['data'];
  $dataHj = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataHoje['data']); 
  $dataHj = $dataHj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[CAD_FUN] (DATA, DATAINI) VALUES (?,?)";

     $params = array($data, $data);

Comment: Legal, Gustavo. Mas você precisa editar sua pergunta e pôr o código lá em vez de nos comentários.

Comment: pronto Café, coloquei lá em cima o código. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua mensagem de erro, você deve estar obtendo nada ou um valor inválido para DateTime na linha `$dataInicio = $_POST['data'];`. Antes de mais nada você precisa resolver isso.

Depois de conseguir criar um `DateTime` com sucesso, ou seja, depois que sua linha `$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataInicio['data']);` funcionar, simplesmente elimine as formatações de datas subsequentes e passe o próprio `DateTime` como parâmetro para a query em vez de passar uma string formatada.

Observe ainda que seu código está sobrescrevendo o valor de variáveis que ele próprio acabou de setar e está setando variáveis que ele não vai usar.

Basicamente retirei do seu código as linhas extras que estão atrapalhando ou são inúteis:

```
if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
        # $dataInicio  = $_POST['data'];
        # $dataHoje = date("Y-m-d");
        # Opção para criar DateTime a partir da data entrada no formulário:
        $data = new DateTime($_POST['data']);
        # $data = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        # $dataHoje['data'] = $_POST['data'];
        # $dataHj = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $dataHoje['data']);
        # $dataHj = $dataHj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[CAD_FUN] (DATA, DATAINI) VALUES (?,?)";
        $params = array($data, $data);
```

Comment: Certo Café, parte eu entendi. Tirei as linhas que disseste para eu tirar. Agora, não entendi a parte que vc diz para eu retirar ou disse que deve ser inválido  valor vindo de $dataInicio = $_POST['data'], pois esse valor estou pegando do formulário, quando o usuário selecionará uma data do calendário. E como fazer, tb, para pegar a data do dia? Pois no php é date("Y-m-d").

Comment: Conseguiu inserrir registros com data? Para obter a data de hoje você pode fazer `$hoje = new DateTime();`.

Comment: Cara, deu um echo e olha o que está vindo nas variáveis:          dataInicio 2014-10-01
dataHoje 2014-09-30

Comment: Vou colocar esse new DateTime();

Comment: Coloquei o $data = new DateTime(); e depois dei um echo pra ver o que vinha e apareceu o seguinte aviso:        Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: Bom dia Café! Mais alguma dica?

Comment: Consegui. O que deve ser feito para pegar a data que o usuário entrar no formulário é $data = new DateTime($_POST['data']).

Comment: @GustavoSevero Que bom, Gustavo! Eu não estava por aqui e só vi tuas mensagens agora. Atualizei na resposta o teu código para DateTime a fim de ficar como referência se mais alguém passar por aqui.

Comment: Caffé, algo estranho está acontecendo. Estou colocando DateTime($_POST['data']), em outro formulário e a data entra no campo com a data "1905-06-06". Sabe o pq isso pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Voltou a funciona. Valeu.